# Grouping and sorting data month wise sorted data showing month and year in ascending order

Tags: sql, database, sorting, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get the data month wise and sorted, for this I tried following query

```
select to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy') "Month", count(id) "No of Persons" 
from Person  
group by to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy')  
order by to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy')
```

and the output I get is

**Month     Number of Persons**

```
Dec-2011    1383  
Feb-2012    1230  
Jan-2012    1409  
Mar-2012    1495  
Nov-2011    985  
Oct-2011    825  
Sep-2011    742
```

Ascending sort on a string value i.e order by to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy') asc

```
select to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy') "Month", count(id) "No of Persons" 
from Person  
group by to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy')  
order by to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy') asc
```

**Month     Number of Persons**

```
Dec-2011    1383  
Feb-2012    1230  
Jan-2012    1409  
Mar-2012    1495  
Nov-2011    985  
Oct-2011    825  
Sep-2011    742
```

Getting the data sorted results in different display of date format

```
 select to_date(to_char(regn_date,'MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY') "Month", count(id) "Number  of  Persons" from Person    
 where trunc(regn_date) < '31-MAR-2012'  
 group by to_date(to_char(regn_date,'MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY')  
 order by to_date(to_char(regn_date,'MM-YYYY'),'MM-YYYY')asc
```

Result:
**Month     Number of Persons**

```
9/1/2011    742    
10/1/2011   825   
11/1/2011   985    
12/1/2011   1383    
1/1/2012    1409    
2/1/2012    1230    
3/1/2012    1495
```

The desired output is date wise sorted data showing month and year in ascending order.

**Month     Number of Persons**

```
Sep-2011    742    
Oct-2011    825       
Nov-2011    985    
Dec-2011    1383    
Jan-2012    1409    
Feb-2012    1230     
Mar-2012    1495
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` to display, use `TO_DATE` for operations.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'Dec-2011' mnth,  1383 persons FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Feb-2012' ,   1230   persons FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Jan-2012',    1409   persons FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Mar-2012',    1495   persons FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'Nov-2011',    985   persons FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'Oct-2011',    825   persons FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'Sep-2011',    742   persons from dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT to_char(to_date(mnth,'Mon-YYYY'), 'Mon-YYYY') mnth, persons
 11    FROM DATA
 12  ORDER BY to_date(mnth,'Mon-YYYY')
 13  /

MNTH                  PERSONS
-------- --------------------
Sep-2011                  742
Oct-2011                  825
Nov-2011                  985
Dec-2011                 1383
Jan-2012                 1409
Feb-2012                 1230
Mar-2012                 1495

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**EDIT** The `WITH` clause is to build the sample table for just demonstration. In your database you need to just rename the DATA with your table name and just execute the select query.

So, your final query would look like,

```
SELECT   to_char(to_date(regn_date,'Mon-YYYY'), 'Mon-YYYY') regn_date, 
         count(id) "No of Persons"
  FROM   person
GROUP BY to_date(regn_date,'Mon-YYYY')
ORDER BY to_date(regn_date,'Mon-YYYY')
/
```

Considering, the `regn_date` is an input as `literal`.

If the `regn_date` is a `date`, then,

```
 SELECT  to_char(regn_date,'Mon-YYYY') regn_date, 
         count(id) "No of Persons"
  FROM   person
GROUP BY to_char(regn_date,'Mon-YYYY')
ORDER BY regn_date
/
```

Comment: WITH DATA AS( )   clause contains hard coded values, how to make this query generic?

Comment: Just remove the `WITH` clause, and in place of `DATA` put `PERSONS` as table name.

Comment: SQL> SELECT   to_char(to_date(sysdate,'Mon-YYYY'), 'Mon-YYYY')     from dual; results in Error. 
 
**ORA-01843: not a valid month**

Comment: `select to_char(sysdate, 'Mon-YYYY') from dual;`

Comment: See the edit above, depends on `regn_date` is `literal` or `date`. Use the query accordingly.

Comment: Is your question answered? Please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort by the actual date, without converting to string:

```
SELECT to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy') "Month", count(id) "No of Persons" 
FROM Person  
GROUP BY to_char(regn_date,'Mon-yyyy')  
ORDER BY regn_date
```

Comment: Hi @bilalhaider if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Truncating the date on month and then converting it to MON-YYYY format did the job.

```
SELECT to_char(TRUNC(regn_date, 'mm'),'MON-YYYY','nls_date_language=american'),count(id)        FROM        Person    
GROUP BY TRUNC(regn_date, 'mm')  
order by TRUNC(regn_date, 'mm')
```

I get the desired output sorted and grouped. Thank you for help.